# How do i import variables from a class in one file to a class in another file?

Tags: python-3.x, class, user-interface, inheritance, pyqt5

i am slightly new to PyQt and making GUIs so bear with me. I have created a UI MainWindow in one file defining the layout, buttons etc. In another file i use the variables and connects them to their relevant functions and buttons. Here comes my problem i have then created a QThread Worker class because i want to keep the GUI responsive when doing some specific task but in this Worker class i dont understand how to import my "self" variables i have been using in my other two classes, i hope it makes somewhat sense.

```
 # This is my imported layout class
import AIM_ToolboxLayout as aimlay

class Worker(QObject, aimlay.Ui_MainWindow):
   finished = pyqtSignal()
   progress = pyqtSignal(int)
   def __init__(self):
      super(Worker, self).__init__()

   def run(self):
    
      for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
    print(self.line_fbound.text())

# This class works as intended
class AIMToolboxFunctions(aimlay.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
    super(AIMToolboxFunctions, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.thread = QThread()
    # Step 3: Create a worker object
    self.worker = Worker()
    # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
    self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
    # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
    self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
    self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
    self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
    self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
    # Step 6: Start the thread
    self.push_run_tab1.clicked.connect(self.thread.start())
```

So in the AIMToolboxFunctions class i can call and work with the variable self.line_fbound because it is imported through self.setupUi(self) coming from the layout class containing the variable. But how do i import the GUI variables from the layout class to my Worker class so i can define what to do in the run function for the worker QThread?

Right now i get this error.

```
AttributeError: 'Worker' object has no attribute 'line_fbound'
```

Comment: First of all, accessing UI elements from an external thread is strictly forbidden, and most certainly leads to fatal crashes. So, the only way to communicate between threads is through signals/slots and thread safe objects (like Queue). In any case, I believe there's some level of misunderstanding: `Ui_MainWindow` is a form class, a simple python object that is used by the *actual* widget class instance (QMainWindow, in your case) to build the UI, so inheriting your worker from Ui_MainWindow would be pointless anyway. The question is, how should your worker interact with the main UI thread?

Comment: @musicamante okay so if i understand you correct i should delete my worker class and initialize a QThread inside my "LongRunningTask" function which freezes the GUI in the main class AIMToolboxFunctions is that correct?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. You *can* communicate with the thread, what you cannot do is *directly* access UI elements (and with access I mean *anything*: creating widgets or getting/setting their properties). You can create and start a thread from anywhere you want, the point is that how that should be implemented completely depends on what I asked: how should your worker interact with the UI? Or, better, should it *really* interact with it? I suggest you to try to clearly explain what you want to do.

Comment: @musicamante, I have a function inside my main class "AIMToolboxFunctions" called "LongRunningTask" this function uses variables from the imported class "AIM_ToolboxLayout" to perform some semi heavy calculations which is why my GUI freezes when i run this function. Therefore i want to run this functions in a worker thread to keep the GUI responsive while running this function, which i was trying to do but without success.

Comment: I doubt that the thread would just start on its own, it would be activated by something in the gui, right? Then just create a function in the main ui class that creates the worker thread with the required variables and start it from there.